# Zend 2.x, setValue from url

Tags: request, zend-framework2

i want to `setValue` in Form class depending on `GET` request. To set value in form i do sth like this :

```
class BookingForm extends Form
{
     $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'end',
        'type' => 'Text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Date to',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => '2013-09-18 15:45',
        ),
    ));
}
```

but it's hard coded and i want avoid this, is there method `$this->getRequest()->get('var to be extracted from url')` ??

Answer (score 0):

I founded solution in :

```
class BookingController extends AbstractActionController
{
     ...
     $get = $request->getQuery('start');
     $get = str_replace('_', ' ', $get);
     $form->get('start')->setValue($get);
     ...
 }
```

and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured a router you can use this:

```
// router
'index' => array(
  'type' => 'Segment',
  'options' => array(
    'route' => '/myvar/:start',
    'constraints' => array(
      'template' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
    ),
    'defaults' => array(
      'controller' => 'module/controller',
      'action' => 'index',
    ),
  ),
),
```

### Controller.php

```
class BookingController extends AbstractActionController
{
     ...
     $get = $this->params("start", "");
     $form->get('start')->setValue($get);
     ...
 }
```